# Is there a difference between "say" and "submit" in court parlance?

Tags: england-and-wales, court, language

In the (senior) courts of England & Wales, a submission given verbally might perhaps be introduced with:

> We say…

or

> We submit…

Strictly speaking, is there some distinction between what it means to "say" something to the court and to actually "submit" it?  (It seems to me that "say" might be for more subjective arguments, but perhaps it is mere stylistic choice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no legal or technical distinction.

Like anything in the English language, sometimes there is a subtle difference conveyed by the choice of words, but most of the time they are equivalent.

Comment: I appreciate that it's somewhat trying to prove a negative, but can you cite any supporting authority?

Comment: If you can raise $30,000 to pay me to do it, I'll trawl court transcripts and interview barristers. :)